# Ширина ячейки по содержимому + text-overflow

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть таблица фиксированной ширины, состоящая из двух колонок.
Необходимо с помощью css выставить:
ширину левой колонки - по содержимому, 
ширину правой - остаток (ширина таблицы - ширина первой колонки) и если необходимо обрезать текст.
Пробовал

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table td:last-child {
    text-align: right;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

В данном случае текст в ячейках "налазит" друг на друга. Пробовал другие способы (без table-layout: fixed) - ширина таблицы увеличивается.
То есть нужен такой вариант:

```
Column1 | Column2
Foo       BarBar

Column1     | Co2
Foooooooooo   B...
```

Answer (score 6):

Если я правильно подозреваю, что колонка, которая по содержимому, не должна содержать многострочный текст, то это делается так:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr :first-child {
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tr :last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Первая колонка
    <th>Вторая колонка
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Какая-то метка
    <td>Есть таблица фиксированной ширины, состоящая из двух колонок. Необходимо с помощью css выставить: ширину левой колонки - по содержимому, ширину правой - остаток (ширина таблицы - ширина первой колонки) и если необходимо обрезать текст. Пробовал
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Упс.. Не заметил, что многоточие надо. Тогда так:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

tr > :first-child {
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

tr > :last-child {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

tr > :last-child > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Первая колонка
    <th>Вторая колонка
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Какая-то метка
    <td><div>Есть таблица фиксированной ширины, состоящая из двух колонок. Необходимо с помощью css выставить: ширину левой колонки - по содержимому, ширину правой - остаток (ширина таблицы - ширина первой колонки) и если необходимо обрезать текст. Пробовал</div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Единственное, что пришло в голову - это сымитировать поведение таблицы дивами.
То есть:
html:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tr clearfix">
        <div class="td">Very-Very Big Content</div>
        <div class="td">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.clearfix {*zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {display: table; line-height: 0; content: ' ';}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}

.table {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.table .tr {display: table-row; background: #bbb;}
.table .tr .td {display: table-cell; padding: 3px;}
.table .tr .td:last-child {
    text-align: right;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 60px; /* ну это на свое усмотрение, естественно */
}
```