# Overflow hidden для table-cell

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! 
Есть родительский класс который определен как `display: table`, в нем два дочерних, в первом может меняться количество символов, необходимо  делать `overflow hidden` и `text-overflow: ellipsis`, для родительского блока. 
Во втором надо сделать чтоб его ширина заполняла все оставшееся пространство родительского блока, и если его нету, то прятать ячейку. 
Частично это реализовано. Нужна помощь с большим количеством символов в первом дочернем блоке.

```css
 .container {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
}

.parent {
    width: 85%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table;
}

.first_child {
    display: table-cell;
}

.second_child {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
 <div class="parent">
  <span class="first_child">Много текста</span>
  <span class="second_child" title="title">*</span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433516/178988

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/610588/178988